# Заполнить textarea из другого класса java

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist, textarea

Есть класс `Main`

```
public class Main extends Application{
    //Объявляем переменные для компонентов формы
    Button button;
    Stage window;
    TextArea zurnal;
    TextArea last10;
    TitledPane titledPaneZurnal;
    TitledPane titledPaneLast10;
    TextField timerText;
    Label l1;



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("TimeCheck");
        window.setResizable(false);
        button = new Button("Открыть");
        zurnal = new TextArea(); //Создаем объект текстового поля для текстового поля с журналом
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                XmlParser.xmlMethod();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XPathExpressionException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        l1 = new Label("Журнал добавленных материалов");
        last10 = new TextArea(); //Создаем объект текстового поля для последних 10 записей
        VBox layout = new VBox(20);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(l1, zurnal, last10, button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 700,500);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

И есть класс **XmlParser**

```
public class XmlParser {
    private static String xmlSource = "http://freerutor.me/rss.xml"; //Ссылка на источник xml
    private static String lastFilm ="";
    public static Main main = new Main();
    static ArrayList<String> searchCopy;


    public static void xmlMethod() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {
        // Создаем DOM
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document bbcDoc = builder.parse(xmlSource);

        ArrayList<String> search = new ArrayList<String>();

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        String expression = "/rss/channel/item"; //выражение для поиска
        NodeList itemNodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, bbcDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET); //создаем список значений


        for (int i = 0; i < itemNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            String expression2 = "title"; //Ищем заголовки в списке
            Node titleInItemNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression2, itemNodes.item(i), XPathConstants.NODE);
            search.add(titleInItemNode.getTextContent()); // Выводим заголовки
        }

        int position = 0;
        boolean flag = false;

        // Определяем последний фильм, по которому будет вестись отбор
        if (search.get(0).trim() != lastFilm.trim()) {
            if (lastFilm != "") {
        // если переменная не пуста, то мы определяем позицию материала, который считался "последним" в прошлой проверке
        //и копируем строки с 0 по по ту, на которой находится этот самый материал

                position = search.indexOf(lastFilm);
                lastFilm = search.get(0).trim();
                if (position > 0) {
                    //searchCopy.clear();
                    searchCopy = new ArrayList<String>(search.subList(0, position));
                    search.clear();
                } else {
                    searchCopy = new ArrayList<String>(search.subList(0, position + 1));
                    search.clear();
                }
            } else { //Если в переменной ничего нет, то мы записываем в нее название последнего добавленного материала на сайт

                lastFilm = search.get(0).trim();
                position = search.indexOf(lastFilm);
                searchCopy = new ArrayList<String>(search.subList(0, position + 1));
            }
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как можно заполнить `zurnal` и `last10` значениями из `search` и `searchCopy` соответственно при вызове метода `XmlParser.xmlMethod()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, кому-то пригодится такое решение:

```
 public static void xmlMethod(Consumer<String> searchResultsConsumer, Consumer<String> searchCopyConsumer ) {
    // ...
    searchCopyConsumer.accept(String.valueOf(searchCopy));
    searchResultsConsumer.accept(String.valueOf(search));
}
```

В `Main` вызываем, например, так:

```
XmlParser.xmlMethod(s -> journal.setText(s.replace(",","\n")), s1 -> last10.appendText(s1.replace(",","\n")));
```