# java некорректно работает таймер

Tags: java

Кое-как решил я свою проблему из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/820892/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-textarea-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-java) вопроса (прикрепил ссылку для того, чтобы показать общий вид классов). Но столкнулся с другой проблемой.
Есть вот такой вот таймер:

```
//объявлены глобально    
Timer timer = new Timer();
XmlParser xmp = new XmlParser();


class TimerFreerutor extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {

        ArrayList<ArrayList> searchMain  = null;
        try {
            searchMain = xmp.xmlMethod().get(0);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<ArrayList> searchCopyMain  = null;
        try {
            searchCopyMain = xmp.xmlMethod().get(1);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        if (!xmp.flag) {

            for (int i = 0; i < searchMain.size(); i++) {
                zurnal.appendText(String.valueOf(searchMain.get(i) + "\n"));
            }

            //if (searchCopyMain.get(1).equals())
            for (int i = 0; i < searchCopyMain.size(); i++) {
                last10.appendText(String.valueOf(searchCopyMain.get(i) + "\n"));
            }

        }
        System.out.println(xmp.flag);
    }
}
```

Вызываю я его в классе `Main` в методе `start` таким вот образом:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerFreerutor(), 0, 60000);
```

Вроде как он работает, но перед своим запуском почему-то вызывается функция `xmp.xmlMethod()` из класса `XmlParser`. Из-за этого данные некорректно обрабатываются. Подскажите, где я в этот раз накосячил?)

Comment: Зачем столько `catch`? Когда есть `multicatch`.

Comment: @And такой вариант предложила intellij idea, вот я особо и не задумывался) Я так понимаю, здесь вариант вроде try{....} catch(Exception ex){...}, как в C#, тоже работает?

Comment: Прочитайте про `multicatch` - `catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException | XPathExpressionException e) {e.printStackTrace();}` - это решается как видите, всего 1 `catch`.

Comment: @And спасибо, почитаю про это. Но что-нибудь по поводу таймера подсказать можете?

Comment: Видимо вы вызываете где-то этот метод, до начала таймера, в этом и проблема.

Comment: @And да вроде бы нет... Вот, все содержимое класса Main: https://pastebin.com/pWb5ZbMS